# Domain sale - Is it DNS hijacking?

Tags: dns-spoofing, domain

I am using a desktop that has two Linux distros and Windows 7 installed, and a laptop with same installation. Both of them are in my **home network**. And sometimes when I try to visit some websites such as **Google**, **BBC** or any of them, it is trying to sell for example **google.com** domain to me; I face with that picture(instead of **7sabah** there has been the website that I am trying to visit.):
[image]

**No matter** which OS ,computer or browser, same problem stands. And I think it may be **DNS Hijacking** but not sure. The link (can be seen in the picture as '**click here**') redirects me to '**4.cn**' website although I am not living in China. Are there any ways I may use to check whether it is a hacking or not?

Comment: Perhaps you have a browser adware extension. Have you tried with different browsers?If the problem doesn't occur in a different browser, then it's something in your browser config, likely an extension. You can disable them all then re-enable them one at a time to figure out which is the bad one.

Answer (score 2):

Your router could be hacked. If your router has or had a default password, you could be victim of drive-by-hijacking. A malicious javascript can try to login to your router, change the DNS settings, and there you are.

If this is the case, this problem is on your home network only. If you take your laptop elsewhere, it should not happen. However, it could be that - if this is the case and they hijacked your DNS - then they could have served malicious scripts to all your computers, infecting them too, in case the router is repaired.

So check your router, and check if you have this problem on other networks as well.